# Angular ng-repeat with header views

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I know the basic use of `ng-repeat` and I can generate a list easily.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="presentation in presentations">
    {{presentation.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have an array that is returned from PHP:

```
presentations = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object (
            [collection] => Collection A
            [title] => Title 1a
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
            [collection] => Collection A
            [title] => Title 2a
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
            [collection] => Collection B
            [title] => Title 1b
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object (
            [collection] => Collection B
            [title] => Title 2b
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object (
            [collection] => Collection C
            [title] => Title 1c
        )
    [5] => stdClass Object (
            [collection] => Collection C
            [title] => Title 2c
        )
    [6] => stdClass Object (
            [collection] => Collection C
            [title] => Title 3c
        )
)
```

You will notice that each object has a `collection`.

I need to basically create a header view per collection. I need it to display like below:

```
COLLECTION A
    - Title 1a
    - Title 2a
COLLECTION B
    - Title 1b
    - Title 2b
COLLECTION C
    - Title 1c
    - Title 2c
    - Title 3c
```

Only the titles would be clickable. Is this possible to do with just `ng-repeat`? I know I can sort each collection into separate arrays in PHP. Should I do that first? I'd like to just use `ng-repeat` if possible, I am just not sure how to approach this.

I plan on displaying this list in a `nav-list` as defined using twitter bootstrap.

[image: nav-list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably other way to achieve this with directives but

http://beta.plnkr.co/KjXZInfrDK9eRid2Rpqf

You define a function that you are going to call in order to show or hide the header:

```
// just a hard coded list of objects, we will output a header when the title changes
$scope.presentations = [{"title":"a", "other":"something else"},{"title":"a", "other":"something else"},{"title":"b", "other":"something else"},{"title":"b", "other":"something else"}, {"title":"b", "other":"something else"}]
$scope.currentTitle = '-1';
$scope.CreateHeader = function(title) {
      showHeader = (title!=$scope.currentTitle); 
       $scope.currentTitle = title;
      return showHeader;
}
```

Your html would look something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="presentation in presentations">
      <div ng-show="CreateHeader(presentation.title)">
        {{presentation.title}} is the header
      </div>
      {{presentation.other}} is an attribute on the collection item
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: should be `presentation in presentations` and not quite. This is actually generating a huge list http://pastie.org/7083218

Comment: It's like I need to store a value of previous collection and then when the current collection is different from the previous collection, make a new header

Comment: I made an adjustment, basically you want to be able to show or hide something and you can do this with the ng-show directive as well as passing in to a function that saves it back to the scope.  I think this setup is what you are after.  There probably are other ways to do this, but it was first and easiest that came to mind.

Comment: excellent, this is exactly what I was after! thank you so much

Comment: you know, now that I think of it, you say this would probably be easier with directives. If you have some spare time or feel like tackling, could you show an example using the directive? I haven't used directives yet. Again, thanks for the answer above

Comment: @Ronnie, Sure I'll do an example, but I don't have a ton of experience with angular either.

Comment: @Ronnie, Here is a simple example with a directive.  http://beta.plnkr.co/1axe45bqqQIdXVUbFRjh   It is just a reusable component that outputs about the same thing as the controller in my other example.

Comment: thanks for the example. That was helpful. I hear directives are a better approach to dom manipulation in angular